# Run Button navigating to Dreamweaver in coldfusion builder

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10, coldfusionbuilder

I am trying to run my project from cf builder 3. When I click on Run or ctrl + F11, I am unable to run the project.

Instead, it is navigating to dreamweaver and the page is opened in DreamWeaver. What should I do to run the page in external browser ?